# How to enforce a quality gate and quality profile for all projects?

Tags: sonarqube

I need to enforce a common quality gate and quality profile to a different project. But if some of the projects create their own gates and profile then the default one is always overridden.

How can I enforce a quality gate and profile? If individual projects create their own with the same list of rules or quality gate metrics then it will be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only allow certain quality profiles and quality gates, you should use **permissions**.

1. Log in as administrator
2. Go to Administration > Security > Global Permissions
3. Only give `Administer Quality Profiles` and `Administer Quality Gates` to a handful, trustworthy people

Other people will not be able to customize quality profiles of quality gates anymore.

Comment: Note that people with Project Administration rights will still be able to choose from the available profiles, so you'd also want to narrow the available profile choices to only the ones you want used.